# Php - Bulk Customer Creation

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Here is my Script which takes 50k records from a CSV and does CRUD operation with them. Unfortunately there are a lot of issues with the performance.

CSV fields are: `msisdn, resellerid, product`

Following are the steps performed:

1. Read the CSV.
2. Create Temp table.
3. Select top 1000 records and mark the status with random string to lock it.
4. Execute these records, meanwhile another request comes to this file then following locked status the next 1000 batch is undertaken.
5. It reads the locked status records and make the API call. If the call is positive then it creates the record of the customer account, else continue for next record's API call .

The code is working fine if we upload a CSV of records 1k, 2k, up to 7k.

When we upload like 10k and above the same records which are in locked status are still called twice thrice and many times, leading to unwanted API calls which needs to be avoided. Sometimes when the API call is successful even then customer account is not getting created.

So I am hereby pasting the code so that highly skilled PHP and Mysql experts can look into the code and suggest their improvement views.

```
<?php
/*********************************************************************************
 ** The contents of this file are subject to the crm CRM Public License Version 1.0
 * ("License"); You may not use this file except in compliance with the License
 * The Original Code is:  crm CRM Open Source
 * The Initial Developer of the Original Code is crm.
 * Portions created by crm are Copyright (C) crm.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 *
 ********************************************************************************/
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000);
set_time_limit(0);

global $adb, $log;
require_once('include/utils/utils.php');
require_once('include/database/PearDatabase.php');
include_once 'includes/main/WebUI.php';

$result   = $adb->pquery("SELECT bulkcustomerid,billingarea,apilogid FROM crm_bulkcustomer where `statusrecord` = 'inprogress'");
$noOfRows = $adb->num_rows($result);

if (!$noOfRows) {
    $result   = $adb->pquery("SELECT bulkcustomerid,billingarea,apilogid FROM crm_bulkcustomer where `statusrecord` = 'new'");
    $noOfRows = $adb->num_rows($result);
}
if (!$noOfRows) {
    // add inner join with crm_crmentity for created date interval day for one day.
    //$result     = $adb->pquery("SELECT bulkcustomerid,billingarea,apilogid FROM crm_bulkcustomer where `statusrecord` = 'closedwithfailure'");
    $result     = $adb->pquery("SELECT bulkcustomerid,billingarea,apilogid FROM crm_bulkcustomer  inner join crm_crmentity on 
                                crm_bulkcustomer.bulkcustomerid=crm_crmentity.crmid where `statusrecord` = 'closedwithfailure'");
    $noOfRows   = $adb->num_rows($result);
    $isClosedWf = TRUE;
}
$process_data = 1000;

$log->debug('TOTAL NUMBEROFCSVS ' . $noOfRows);

$length       = 9;
$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

if ($noOfRows > 0) { // for number of csv files .
    for ($i = 0; $i < $noOfRows; $i++) {
        $bulkcustomerid = $adb->query_result($result, $i, 'bulkcustomerid');
        $apilogid       = $adb->query_result($result, $i, 'apilogid'); // update the records for processing 
        $billingarea       = $adb->query_result($result, $i, 'billingarea');  
        if (!$apilogid) {
            $apilogid = 0;
        }

        $adb->query("UPDATE crm_bulkcustomer SET `statusrecord` = 'inprogress' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");

        if ($isClosedWf) {
            $log->debug('IN CLOSED WITH FAILURE PART');
            //sleep(6800);
            $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '$randomString' where STATUS = '0' OR STATUS REGEXP '[a-z]' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $process_data");

            $servicetype = "Prepaid";
            $log->debug('CRON TASK - After validating Call Create Customer API for Record ID ' . $bulkcustomerid);
            $log->debug('select msisdn,package from temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where status=' . $randomString . ' limit' . $process_data . ' FOR UPDATE');
            //$transaction = "START TRANSACTION;";
            //$adb->pquery($transaction, array());
            $result2   = $adb->query("select msisdn,package from temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where status='$randomString' limit $process_data");
            $noOfRows2 = $adb->num_rows($result2);

            $log->debug('Total row for this table is:- ' . $noOfRows2);
            if ($noOfRows2 > 0) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < $noOfRows2; $j++) {
                    $msisdnnum = $adb->query_result($result2, $j, 'msisdn');
                    $package   = $adb->query_result($result2, $j, 'package');
                   /***** commented MSISDN 
                    $log->debug('CRON TASK - Call Create Customer API for Table ID temp_csv_' . $bulkcustomerid . 'and mobile number is' . $msisdnnum);
                    $log->debug("for IF part BulkCustomer_SearchSim_Action::search_msisdn($msisdnnum,$apilogid)");
                    $result1 = BulkCustomer_SearchSim_Action::search_msisdn($msisdnnum, $apilogid, $bulkcustomerid);
                    $message = $result1['message'];
                    $code    = $result1['code'];
                    if ($code == 0) {
                        $log->debug('MESSAGE IS--for code 0 ' . $message . 'code is--' . $code);
                        $log->debug('Sucess UPDATE crm_bulkcustomer SET statusrecord = closed where bulkcustomerid=' . $bulkcustomerid);
                        ******/
                        $bulkresult = BulkCustomer_CreateCustomer_Action::Create_Customer($msisdnnum, $bulkcustomerid, $package, $servicetype,$billingarea,$apilogid);
                        $log->debug('CUSTOMER WITH ALL ACCOUNTS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY FOR MOBILENO=' . $msisdnnum . 'and current j value is=' . $j . 'and no of records to parse are' . $noOfRows2);
                        $bulkcode    = $bulkresult['code'];
                        $bulkmessage = $bulkresult['message'];

                        if ($bulkcode == '0') {
                            $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '1',remarks='$bulkmessage' where `msisdn` = '$msisdnnum'");
                        } else {
                            $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '-6',remarks='$bulkmessage' where `msisdn` = '$msisdnnum'");
                        }
                   /****** search MSISDN } else {
                        $log->debug('MESSAGE IS-- for code -1 ' . $message . 'code is--' . $code);
                        $log->debug('Failure UPDATE temp_csv_' . $bulkcustomerid . 'SET status = Failed where msisdn =' . $msisdnnum);
                        $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '-9',remarks='$message' where `msisdn` = '$msisdnnum'");
                    }
                    search MSISDN *****/
                    $log->debug('j value is for loop' . $j);
                }
            }else{
              $log->debug('No data to parse');
              $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `statusrecord` = 'closed' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");
            }

        } else { // for locking the columns with -7
            $log->debug('IN PROGESS OR NEW PART');
            $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '$randomString' where `status` = '0' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $process_data");
            $servicetype = "prepaid";
            $log->debug('CRON TASK - After validating Call Create Customer API for Record ID ' . $bulkcustomerid);
            $log->debug('select msisdn,package from temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where status=' . $randomString . ' limit' . $process_data . 'FOR UPDATE');
            //$transaction = "START TRANSACTION;";
            //$adb->pquery($transaction, array());
            $result2   = $adb->query("select msisdn,package from temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where status='$randomString' limit $process_data");
            $noOfRows2 = $adb->num_rows($result2);
            $log->debug('Total row for this table is:- ' . $noOfRows2);
            if ($noOfRows2 > 0) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < $noOfRows2; $j++) {
                    $msisdnnum = $adb->query_result($result2, $j, 'msisdn');
                    $package   = $adb->query_result($result2, $j, 'package');
                    /***** commented MSISDN 
                    $log->debug("ELSE BulkCustomer_SearchSim_Action::search_msisdn($msisdnnum,$apilogid)");
                    $result1 = BulkCustomer_SearchSim_Action::search_msisdn($msisdnnum, $apilogid, $bulkcustomerid);
                    $message = $result1['message'];
                    $code    = $result1['code'];
                    if ($code == 0) {
                        $log->debug('MESSAGE IS--for code 0 ' . $message . 'code is--' . $code);
                        $log->debug('Sucess UPDATE crm_bulkcustomer SET statusrecord = closed where bulkcustomerid=' . $bulkcustomerid);
                        ******/
                        $bulkresult = BulkCustomer_CreateCustomer_Action::Create_Customer($msisdnnum, $bulkcustomerid, $package, $servicetype,$billingarea,$apilogid);
                        $log->debug('CUSTOMER WITH ALL ACCOUNTS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY FOR MOBILENO=' . $msisdnnum . 'and current j value is=' . $j . 'and no of records to parse are' . $noOfRows2);
                        $bulkcode    = $bulkresult['code'];
                        $bulkmessage = $bulkresult['message'];

                        if ($bulkcode == '0') {
                            $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '1',remarks='$bulkmessage' where `msisdn` = '$msisdnnum'");
                        } else {
                            $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '-6',remarks='$bulkmessage' where `msisdn` = '$msisdnnum'");
                        }
                  /******  } else {
                        $log->debug('Failure UPDATE temp_csv_' . $bulkcustomerid . 'SET status = Failed where msisdn =' . $msisdnnum);
                        $adb->query("UPDATE temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid SET `status` = '-9',remarks='$message' where `msisdn` = '$msisdnnum'");
                    }
                     comments ends for MSISDN ****/
                    $log->debug('j value is for loop' . $j);
                }
            }else{
              $log->debug('No data to parse inprogress or new part');
              $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `statusrecord` = 'closedwithfailure' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");
            }
            //commit
        } // for else part
        // close the csv file 
        // get count of sucess and failure.
        $sucesscount = $adb->pquery("SELECT * FROM temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where `status` = '1'"); // fetch record for new
        $noofsucess  = $adb->num_rows($sucesscount);
        $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `successcount` = '$noofsucess' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");

        // failure count
        $failurecount       = $adb->pquery("SELECT * FROM temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where status!='1'"); // fetch record for fails
        $nooffailure        = $adb->num_rows($failurecount);
        $reprocesscount     = $adb->pquery("SELECT * FROM temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where  STATUS = '0' OR STATUS REGEXP '[a-z]'");
        // fetch record for fails
        //$noofreprocesscount = 0;
        $noofreprocesscount = $adb->num_rows($reprocesscount);
        $log->debug("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `failurecount` = '$nooffailure' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");
        if ($nooffailure == '0') {
            $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `statusrecord` = 'closed' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");
            $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `failurecount` = '' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");
        } elseif ($noofreprocesscount) {
            // check if it is being closed before all records are executed 
            $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `statusrecord` = 'inprogress' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");
        } else {
            $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `failurecount` = '$nooffailure' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");
            $adb->query("UPDATE `crm_bulkcustomer` SET `statusrecord` = 'closedwithfailure' where `bulkcustomerid` = '$bulkcustomerid'");

            $filename = "$bulkcustomerid" . "-csv";
            $file     = fopen("tempcsv/$filename.csv", "w");
            $val      = array(
                'MSISDN',
                'ResellerID',
                'Package',
                'Remarks'
            );
            fputcsv($file, $val, ';', ' ');
            $csvresult = $adb->query("select msisdn,package,resellerid,remarks from temp_csv_$bulkcustomerid where status!='1' ");
            $csvrows   = $adb->num_rows($csvresult);
            $log->debug('Total row for this table in CSV PART is:- ' . $csvrows);
            if ($csvrows > 0) {
                for ($m = 0; $m < $csvrows; $m++) {
                    $msisdnnum  = $adb->query_result($csvresult, $m, 'msisdn');
                    $package    = $adb->query_result($csvresult, $m, 'package');
                    $resellerid = $adb->query_result($csvresult, $m, 'resellerid');
                    $remarks    = $adb->query_result($csvresult, $m, 'remarks');
                    $remarks    = preg_replace('/\s+/', '--', $remarks);
                    $arrayval   = array(
                        "$msisdnnum",
                        "$resellerid",
                        "$package",
                        "$remarks"
                    );
                    fputcsv($file, $arrayval, ';', ' ');

                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    $log->debug('No status with NEW or Pending of CSV RECORDS found');
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the MySql function [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) ? You'll be able to read a 100k line csv file within seconds. It has always been my friend with data imports

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @pierre ,
read is not an issue for now ,but performing entire crud operation in an issue .so if you can just review the code and put your expert suggestions that would be great.

Comment: @riggs ,
this can help someone who wants the same sort of solutions ,voting against some question will not be the solution of the query .Apart if you have solution pls put it to use for us .

Comment: It takes 4 other people to agree with me before the question is put on hold. If 5 people all agree that this question is not on topic for this site then it is almost definitely not on topic. I did suggest where you could get some help, I would post your question there and see if they are prepared to help you. Also notice that in 2 hours, you have received no answers, that should tell you something. Normally you will get some sort of answer here within 5 minutes anytime day or night

Comment: Okay Thanks ,
Posted the question there too .

Answer (score 0):

One reason of this could be that out of these 50K records that you have, maybe a few of the entries(after 7K) are vague and that is giving you the problem.

So maybe try to create chunk of records and try to figure out which one of the chunk is giving you an issue and try to figure out that entry. This is just a general idea.